# Python loop not reading through Beautifulsoup contents

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I wrote a for-loop that I thought was extracting the text from the html elements that I had indicated using the Beautifulsoup library. It looks like this:

```
url = "https://www.researchgate.net/profile/David_Severson"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = bsoup(data, "lxml")

item = soup.find("div", {"class": "section section-research"})
papers = [paper for paper in item.find_all("div", {"class": "nova-o-stack__item"})] 


for p in papers:

    title = p.find("div", {"class": "nova-e-text nova-e-text--size-l nova-e-text--family-sans-serif nova-e-text--spacing-none nova-e-text--color-inherit nova-v-publication-item__title nova-v-publication-item__title--clamp-3"})
    abstract = p.find("div", {"class": "nova-e-text nova-e-text--size-m nova-e-text--family-sans-serif nova-e-text--spacing-none nova-e-text--color-inherit nova-v-publication-item__description nova-v-publication-item__description--clamp-3"})
    views = p.find("ul", {"class": "nova-e-list nova-e-list--size-m nova-e-list--type-inline nova-e-list--spacing-none nova-v-publication-item__metrics"})
    date = p.find("li", {"class": "nova-e-list__item publication-item-meta-items__meta-data-item"})
    authors = p.find("ul", {"class": "nova-e-list nova-e-list--size-m nova-e-list--type-inline nova-e-list--spacing-none nova-v-publication-item__person-list"})
    link = p.find("a", {"class": "nova-e-badge nova-e-badge--color-green nova-e-badge--display-block nova-e-badge--luminosity-high nova-e-badge--size-l nova-e-badge--theme-solid nova-e-badge--radius-m nova-v-publication-item__type"}, href=True)

    if link:

             full_link = urllib.parse.urljoin("https://www.researchgate.net/", link["href"])
             print(full_link)


    print(p.text)
```

I noticed that it was printing out more than what I had indicated in the contents of the loop. After trying to debug each of the individual items (title, abstract etc...), I realized the loop was not even accessing the items therein at all.

For example, if I commented them all out, or totally remove them, it still gave the **exact** same output:

```
for p in papers:




    print(p.text)
    print("")
```

(This ^ gives me the exact same output as the code *with* the contents in the body.)

Somehow the loop is not even reading the elements it's supposed to be using to iterate through p...How can I get it to recognize the script contained therein, and extract the desired elements as defined by the elements I have (or thought I had) written in the body of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have space in your class that you specified

```
papers = [paper for paper in item.find_all("div", {"class": "nova-o-stack__item"})]
```

I removed the space and your code worked. so retry it by using this code.

Comment: I appreciate the reply, but this is not the problem. In my actual script there is no space. This was just how Stackoverflow formatted it. It looks like that in my actual script. The problem persists.